# How can I replace HTML code in Notepad++ using RegEx

Tags: php, html, regex, notepad++

I have a lot of php pages. Every php page has inside a string like this:

```
<FONT COLOR="#0000FF">Post ID: 16107</FONT>
```

and I'd like to replace with:

```
<A HREF="#16107">Post ID: 16107</A>
```

but since every php page has a different Post ID and I'd like to match every occurrence of the string... I use as usually notepad2 witch supports regex and notepad++ too that supports regex as well. How can I replace all strings into all files into all dirs? Are about 350 files...

Answer (score 2):

*Replace:* `<FONT COLOR=".*?">(Post ID: ([0-9]+))</FONT>`

*With:* `<A HREF="#\2">\1</A>`

Comment: +1. Ignore the other answers that tell you to use the $ to for match replacement -- Notepad++ doesn't support that. I suspect they don't use Notepad++, which uses the backslash: `\1`, as amiregelz shows you here.

Comment: @Faust Apparently, Notepad++ does support `$` for referencing regex groups.

Comment: @JohnCorbett: OK, you're right. I just upgraded my version of Notepad++ and found that it works now. Must be a recent change.

Comment: Yes, Notepad++ only supported standard [POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) Regular Expressions in the past, but they added full [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) Search/Replace support in one of their latest versions. PCRE's is more powerful and flexible than the POSIX regex.

Answer (score 1):

search for

`<FONT COLOR=".*?">Post ID: (\d+)<\/FONT>`

replace with

`<A HREF="#$1">Post ID: $1<\/A>`

Comment: `$1` does not represent first group in notepad++. It is `\1`

Comment: Worked fine! more of 530 files replaced. Thanks to all people for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Good to know this is possible:

In Notepad++ you'd need to search for `Keep ID: ([0-9]*)` and replace it with `New ID: $1`.

- `$0` represents the whole thing found, `$1` the first found in brackets.
- you can use `[]` to create a class (in this case of numbers 0 to 9)
- and finally the asterisk tells the parser to repeat the previuos character or character class as often as possible.