# notepad++ - delete attributes in HTML start tags with regex

Tags: html, regex, replace, attributes, notepad++

Solution:

Find: `<([a-z]+) .?=".?( */?>)`

Replace with: `<\1$2`

---

I usually copy tables from forum sites to blog sites.

I want no attribute in all start tags.
The tables are like this:

```
1|<table unwanted_attribute_1>
2|<tbody unwanted_attribute_2>
3|<tr unwanted_attribute_3><td unwanted_attribute_4><br unwanted_attribute_5 /></td></tr>
4|<tr unwanted_attribute_3><td unwanted_attribute_4><span unwanted_attribute_6></span></td></tr>
5|</tbody>
6|</table>
Attributes like "cellspacing", "class", "style", "href" and "target".
```

I found two answers but they do not seem to be helpful.
[[A1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791003/regex-notepad-html-search-replace#answer-22791954)]: It uses a fixed condition to find and replace specific terms. But in my situation, start tags are everywhere and vary with the article.
[[A2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847147/how-can-i-replace-html-code-in-notepad-using-regex#answer-11847469)]: I tried this answer but it is not working as follows.

I find `<([a-z]+) .*=".*">` and replace with `<\1>`.
Line 1 and 2 works but line 3 and 4 messed up.

How should I use regex?

EDIT:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="t_table" style="background-color: #f8f8f8; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); color: #444444; empty-cells: show; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; table-layout: auto; width: 673px; word-wrap: break-word;">
<tbody style="word-wrap: break-word;">
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆<a class="relatedlink" href="◆◆◆" style="border-bottom: 1px solid blue; color: #639805; word-wrap: break-word;" target="_blank">◆◆</a>◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆<br style="word-wrap: break-word;" />◆◆◆◆</td></tr>
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">= ◆◆◆◆ =<br style="word-wrap: break-word;" /></td></tr>
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">= ◆◆◆◆ =<br style="word-wrap: break-word;" /></td></tr>
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">= ◆◆◆◆ =<br style="word-wrap: break-word;" /></td></tr>
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆</td></tr>
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;"><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆◆◆</td><td style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 237, 245); overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; word-wrap: break-word;">◆◆◆◆</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.*` is greedy so it matches everything until the last `">` on your line. Here's what your first regex does:

https://regex101.com/r/qK5uY3/1

Try:

```
<([a-z]+) .*?=".*? *\/?>
```

I'd recommend looking at plugins for notepad++. There can be many issues using a regex to parse HTML.

https://regex101.com/r/qK5uY3/2

The `*\/?` before the closing `>` is matching optional whitespace and a self closing element. The `\h` I prefer to use but I don't know if Notepad++ supports that (I'm mac'er).

**Update:**

To capture the closing bit of the self closing element group the full closing part.

```
<([a-z]+) .*?=".*?( *\/?>)
```

then replace with the 2nd captured group.

```
<\1$2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qK5uY3/3

Comment: Thanks for the solution. `.*? *?>` is the key point to distinguish `>` in a line. `\/` is really optional. But how can I retain `<br />`?

Comment: Oh, you need to retain the self-closing? I think if you capture that it'd work. https://regex101.com/r/qK5uY3/3